# Adding stock images to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-image

I have an iOS background and am used to dragging and dropping images. I am trying to create an Android version of my game, and I am encountering an issue when I copy and paste the .png images into res/drawable. For some reason, I am getting the following error message

```
Image not loaded
Try to open it externally to fix format problem
```

The file name is "back_arrow.png"

How would I add these stock images to my Android Studio project?

Comment: What's the filename and extension?

Comment: Edited my OP, the file name is "back_arrow.png"

Comment: Just a few suggestions: 1. try opening the file on your desktop. 2. Make sure you don't have a file with the same name in your Drawable folder (even if it has a different extension)

Comment: Hey Udi, I actually found the problem. In iOS, I was using an alias of the original image rather than the original PNG file. For some reason, Xcode doesn't complain about this but Android Studio does. Thanks for the help!

Comment: In my solution, after editing the image by paint.exe(just paint some white point) and saving, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, I was using an alias of the original image rather than the original PNG file. For some reason, Xcode doesn't complain about this but Android Studio does.